# Anydesk installation by bash script using wget

Tags: html-parsing, wget

I'm trying to write a bash script for automating the installation of anydesk by wget with the help of the following code:

```
echo -e "[ - ] Installing AnyDesk..."
wget --max-redirect 1 --trust-server-names 'https://anydesk.com/en/downloads/thank-you?dv=deb_64' -O anydesk.deb
sudo apt install ./anydesk.deb
echo -e "[ ✔ ] AnyDesk ➜ INSTALLED\n"
```

The problem is that `https://anydesk.com/en/downloads/thank-you?dv=deb_64` returns a HTML page, not a Debian package.

How can I parse the HTML page to find the download link to the Debian package?

Answer (score 1):

I examined page source of https://anydesk.com/en/downloads/thank-you?dv=deb_64 and download is triggered by JavaScript depending on User-Agent of browser, `wget` does not support JavaScript execution therefore you are actually getting HTML page source not actual .deb file. Use tool which support JavaScript execution to get actual file.

Comment: can you suggest any tool?

Comment: @MuhammadHabib I suggest taking look at [PhantomJS](https://phantomjs.org/)

Answer (score 0):

You can run the following command:

```
wget -O anydesk.deb https://download.anydesk.com/linux/anydesk_6.2.1-1_amd64.deb
```

this will allow you to download Anydesk, via wget.